Threading communication in python
I'm trying to make a custom groundstation for drones in python, i have one class that handles the UI and editing attributes from drones inside a drones list. The second class SerialCom handles the serial communication and threading involved, i would like it to work in such a way that the serialCom class constantly sends the attributes of the drones over serial to a ESP32(the serial connection works). My question is how the serialCom class can access the drone's attributes from inside the thread. This is part of my code that I currently have related to sending data, I left out the UI-related code:
class GroundControlApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.serial_com_instance = None
        self.DataTelemetry_instance = None
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Drone Ground Station")
        self.root.configure(bg="#141414")
        self.drones = []
        self.Drone_counter = 0
        self.drone_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.connection_status_label = None
        window_width = 1500
        window_height = 750
        self.root.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}")
        
        #in this part would be all the UI related setup(not included because this is all works)
        
        #example function for how i edit the drone attributes(this code also works)
     def move(self, axis, direction):
        distance = self.get_selected_distance()
        if axis == "X":
            self.drones[self.get_DroneIndex()].target_position[0] += distance if direction == "forward" else -distance
        elif axis == "Y":
            self.drones[self.get_DroneIndex()].target_position[1] += distance if direction == "right" else -distance
        elif axis == "Z":
            self.drones[self.get_DroneIndex()].target_position[2] += distance if direction == "up" else -distance
        

#function to toggle the serial connection and update the related UI elements
    def Toggle_Connection(self):
        if not self.serial_com_instance:
            self.serial_com_instance = SerialCom(self.get_selected_ComPort())
            if self.serial_com_instance.connect():
                self.connect_button.config(text="Disconnect")
                self.connection_status_label.config(text="Connected")
            else:
                self.connection_status_label.config(text="Error") 
        else:
            if self.serial_com_instance.connected:
                if self.serial_com_instance.disconnect():
                    self.connect_button.config(text="Connect")
                    self.connection_status_label.config(text="Disconnected")
                else:
                    self.connection_status_label.config(text="Error")
            else:
                if self.serial_com_instance.connect():
                    self.connect_button.config(text="Disconnect")
                    self.connection_status_label.config(text="Connected")
                else:
                    self.connection_status_label.config(text="Error")


class SerialCom:
    def __init__(self, port, baudrate=115200):
        self.port = port
        self.baudrate = baudrate
        self.serial_port = None
        self.connected = False
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.send_thread = None


    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.serial_port = serial.Serial(self.port, self.baudrate)
            self.connected = True 
            self.start_sending_thread()
            return True
        except serial.SerialException as e:
            print(f"Failed to connect to serial port: {e}")
            return False

    def disconnect(self):
        try:
            if self.serial_port:
                self.stop_sending_thread()
                self.serial_port.close()
                print("Serial connection closed.")
                self.connected = False
                return True
            else:
                print("Serial port is not connected.")
                return False
        except serial.SerialException as e:
            print(f"Failed to close serial port: {e}")
            return False

    def start_sending_thread(self):
        if not self.send_thread or not self.send_thread.is_alive():
            self.stop_event.clear()
            self.send_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.send_data)
            self.send_thread.start() 

    def stop_sending_thread(self):
        if self.send_thread and self.send_thread.is_alive():
            self.stop_event.set()
            self.send_thread.join()

    def send_data(self): 
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            try:
                #from here on is my problem, i used placeholder "drone" but this needs to acces the attributes from the GroundControlApp class
                for drone in self.drones:
                    data = struct.pack('<3i 3i i 3i s b ', drone.current_position[0], drone.current_position[1], drone.current_position[2],
                                       drone.target_position[0], drone.target_position[1], drone.target_position[2],
                                       drone.home_position[0], drone.home_position[1], drone.home_position[2],
                                       drone.mode.encode(), drone.armed)
                    self.serial_port.write(data)
                print("Data sent successfully.")
                time.sleep(0.1) # sleep for 0.1 seconds
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Failed to send data: {e}")
                break

class Drone:
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index
        self.current_position = [0, 0, 0]
        self.target_position = [0, 0, 0]
        self.home_position = [0, 0, 0]
        self.Mode = "Position Hold"
        self.is_armed = False
        self.start_time = 0
        self.end_time = 0
        self.flight_time = 0
        self.RSSI = 0
        self.BatVoltage = 0
        self.BatCurrent = 0
        self.PID_XYZ = [0, 0, 0]
        self.PID_RPY = [0, 0, 0]

    @property
    def current_position(self):
        return self._current_position

    @current_position.setter
    def current_position(self, position):
        self._current_position = position

#all the other getters and setters for al the drone attributes

I tried importing the Groundcontrolapp as an instance to the serialCom class and this works but then the data is not right when you edit the attributes from the drones inside the drones list via the UI
